# update data.table subset with function

Tags: r, function, data.table, sapply

I have a data.table

```
dt2 <- data.table(urn=1:10,freq=0, freqband="")
dt2$freqband = NA
dt2$freq <- 1:7 #does give a warning message
##    urn freq freqband
## 1:   1    1       NA
## 2:   2    2       NA
## 3:   3    3       NA
## 4:   4    4       NA
## 5:   5    5       NA
## 6:   6    6       NA
## 7:   7    7       NA
## 8:   8    1       NA
## 9:   9    2       NA
##10:  10    3       NA
```

i also have a function that I am wanting to use to group my freq column

```
fn_GetFrequency <- function(numgifts) {
    if (numgifts <5) return("<5")
    if (numgifts >=5) return("5+")
    return("ERROR")
}
```

I am wanting to set the freqband column based on this function. In some cases it will be all records, in some cases it will be a subset. My current approach is (for a subset):

```
dt2[dt2$urn < 9, freqband := fn_GetFrequency(freq)]
```

using this approach I get the warning:

```
Warning message:
In if (numgifts < 5) return("<5") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

then it sets all the records to have  a value of "<5" rather than the correct value. I'm figuring that I need to use some sort of lapply/sapply/etc function, however I still haven't been able to quite grasp how they work in order to use them to solve my problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: How might you do this if you use a function that requires 2 parameters?

UPDATED: to include the output of dt2 after my attempted update

```
    urn freq freqband
 1:   1    1       <5
 2:   2    2       <5
 3:   3    3       <5
 4:   4    4       <5
 5:   5    5       <5
 6:   6    6       <5
 7:   7    7       <5
 8:   8    1       <5
 9:   9    2       NA
10:  10    3       NA
```

UPDATE: I tried this code to and it worked to deliver the desired output, and it allows me to have a function I can call in other places of code too.

```
dt2[dt2$urn < 9, freqband := sapply(freq, fn_GetFrequency)]
```

Comment: That function you defined would always return "ERROR". You need to learn to the difference between `if` and 'ifelse`. R is not SAS.

Comment: @BondedDust I don't get "ERROR" for any of them as the first value meets the first condition, thus returning "<5", which I think is cascading the value for freqband where the subset is met. The error is there purely as a catchall if none of the previous conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> fn_GetFrequency <- function(numgifts) {
+     ifelse (numgifts <5, "<5", "5+")
+ }
> dt2[dt2$urn < 9, freqband := fn_GetFrequency(freq)]
> dt2
    urn freq freqband
 1:   1    1       <5
 2:   2    2       <5
 3:   3    3       <5
 4:   4    4       <5
 5:   5    5       5+
 6:   6    6       5+
 7:   7    7       5+
 8:   8    1       <5
 9:   9    2       NA
10:  10    3       NA
```

For multiple bands (which I'm sure has been asked before) you should use the `findInterval` function. And I'm doing it the data.table way reather than the dataframe way:

```
dt2[ urn==8, freq := -1 ] # and something to test the <0 condition

dt2[ urn <= 8, freqband := c("ERROR", "<5", "5+")[
                                  findInterval(freq,c(-Inf, 0, 5 ,Inf))] ]
dt2
    urn freq freqband
 1:   1    1       <5
 2:   2    2       <5
 3:   3    3       <5
 4:   4    4       <5
 5:   5    5       5+
 6:   6    6       5+
 7:   7    7       5+
 8:   8   -1    ERROR
 9:   9    2       NA
10:  10    3       NA
```

Comment: admittedly this solution does work for the specific example above, and i was a little narrow sighted in the function I used. I should have used if(numgifts >0 & numgifts<5) return("<5")... as this would have then had the case of returning "ERROR" should be freq value be <1. But further to this what if you've got more than the 2 freq bands? e.g. 1-2,3-4,5-8,8+

Comment: Use either `cut` or `findInterval`.